# Cardinality of a power set is given be $2^n$. Why?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Cardinality of power set of $A$ is determined by $2^n$, where n is the number of elements in Set $A$. How does this formula work?

I was taught that there are $n$ elements in Set $A$ and each element has a choice of either being in the power set or not i.e., $2$ choices. Hence $\underbrace{ 2\times 2\times 2\times 2 \cdots}_{n\; times}  $.

But I don't understand why the element's choice of either being in the power set or not helps us in determining the cardinality of the power set.

Comment: That is exactly the argument, except they have a choice of being in a subset which is in the power set.

Comment: So why does the above formula work?

Comment: @FFjet Sorry, I am not sure I understand you.

Comment: @Kaushik I mean that your explanation is right.

Comment: Please check the edited question. Thanks!

Comment: We prove it; see [Cardinality of the Power-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Properties).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I was taught that there are n elements in Set A and each element has a choice of either being in the power set or not i.e., 2 choices.*

By definition, the power set of $A$ is the set of all subsets of $A$. The power set of $A$ does not contain *elements* of $A$, it contains *subsets* of $A$.

In how many ways can you choose a subset (say, $X$) of $A$? Well, every element in $A$ has a choice of either being in $X$ or not, i.e. $2$ choices. Thus there are $2^n$ ways you can form a subset $X$. Thus the total number of subsets is $2^n$.

To summarize: your mistake seems to be that you have swapped "*choice being in $X$*" (where $X$ is a subset) to "*choice being in the power set*".

Comment: But I don't understand why the element's choice of either being in the subset or not helps us in determining the cardinality of the power set.

Comment: Let's go by example. One subset of $A$ is the empty set $X=\emptyset$. This is the result if all elements of $A$ "choose" to *not* be in $X$. Another subset of $A$ is the whole $X=A$. This is the result if all elements of $A$ "choose" to *be* in $X$. Pick another subset $X\subseteq A$. This is the result if those elements that are in $X$ "choose" to *be* in $X$, and those that are not "choose" to *not* be. Every possible "choice" of the elements gives you a subset and vice versa. Thus the number of possible subsets is the same as the number of possible "choices".

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice exercise for mathematical induction. It follows from these observations:

Assume that $X$ is a nonempty set and let $x_0\in X$ be a fixed element. Now let

$$T_{x_0}=\{A\subset X\ |\ x_0\in A\}$$
$$U_{x_0}=\{B\subset X\ |\ x_0\not\in B\}$$

The following properties are straightforward:

$$U_{x_0}=P(X\backslash\{x_0\})$$
$$P(X)=T_{x_0}\cup U_{x_0}$$
$$T_{x_0}\cap U_{x_0}=\emptyset$$

The crucial observation is that

$$|T_{x_0}|=|U_{x_0}|$$

I encourage you to construct such a bijection by yourself. All those facts together give

$$|P(X)|=2\cdot |P(X\backslash\{x_0\})|$$

and now you apply mathematical induction. Can you complete the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Impose an order on $A$. You can think of each subset in terms of the $n$-bit string that tells you which elements it has, with the $i$th bit $1$ if the $i$th element of $A$ is to be included, or $0$ if it isn't. If $A$ is infinite so that $A$ is a transfinite cardinal, this argument still works (but then your string is infinite, and if uncountable you shouldn't even think of it as a string, but rather a function from elements of $A$ to $\{0,\,1\}$ - which also means we don't need to order $A$ any more), so @freakish's use of induction, which wouldn't carry over to that case, isn't needed. However, this is really how we *define* $2^n$ for $n$ transfinite.

Answer (score 1):

**Computer scientists favorite proof**...

Let $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ be a set. A subset of $B$ can be represented by a bit vector $b \in \{0,1\}^n$ where 
$$
b_i = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $a_i \in B$}\\
0 &\text{if $a_i \notin B$}
\end{cases}
$$
For instance, the subset $\{2,3, 5, 7\}$ of $\{1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$ is represented by the bit vector $(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)$. This gives you a bijection between $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\{0,1\}^n$ and thus $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = 2^n$.